# Запятые в обороте "потому что"

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется такое предложение: "Квартира продавалась потому, что жить в ней было невозможно, а невозможно жить, потому что страшно". Правильно ли тут разбиты запятыми оба оборота "потому что"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, составной союз "потому что" положено записывать в придаточном предложении, то есть запятая должна стоять перед союзом, как это показано в конце Вашего предложения ("потому что страшно"). Однако при необходимости интонационного выделения слова "потому", которое в этом случае выполняет в предложении роль указательного (соотносительного) слова главного предложения, союз "потому что" делится на две части. При этом одна часть (в Вашем предложении это слово "потому") остается в главном предложении, затем ставится запятая, и придаточное предложении начинается с союза "что".