# Пунктуация в предложении с союзом "потому что"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

> Иван каркал по-вороньи, потому что проиграл спор с Ильёй.

Где должны быть запятые?

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10108/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429841/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be

Answer (score 2):

[**потому(,) что**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138)
Это сложный (составной) подчинительный союз, который может расчленяться в зависимости от смысла или интонации.

Вот ситуация, в которой в первую очередь выясняется **причина** особого поведения:
— Почему он каркал?
— Иван каркал по-вороньи потому, что проиграл спор с Ильёй.

А вот другая, в которой упор делается на **сам факт** произошедшего:
— И что же он делал?
— Иван каркал по-вороньи, потому что проиграл спор с Ильёй.

Место знака препинания определяется самим пишущим — это зависит от конкретных целей высказывания. Но такие "вариации" с запятой не всегда возможны.
Про особенности пунктуации можно прочитать здесь:
[ПОТОМУ ЧТО или ПОТОМУ, ЧТО](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.31)

Answer (score 0):

Два варианта возможны.

1. Нейтральный. Главное — сообщить о том, что Иван каркал по-вороньи, а лишь затем мы раскрываем причину:

**Иван каркал по-вор**О**ньи, потому что проиграл спор с Ильёй.**

2. Главное в этом сообщении — причина (скорее всего, сам факт уже известен). Иван каркал по-вороньи именно по этой причине, а не по какой-либо другой:

**Иван каркал по-вороньи потом**У, **что проиграл спор с Ильёй.**